# PHP MySQLi prepared statement bind errors on certain characters?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, bind

First time posting to StackOverflow, but I've been a long time reader of the comments here.

I ran across a programming bug that I could not figure out after several hours, and couldn't find anything in the questions and responses that seemed to apply, so here goes my first post!

I'm using PHP and a MySQLi prepared statement to insert data that originates from a file into a database and stores each record from the file into an array ($dbData[]) that is passed to a function that performs the database storage. I have checked the array values for all four indices for each record and data exists in all record fields, although there is a lot of slashes (forward and backwards), apostrophes, quotes (single and double) and html tags in some of the string content.

The $dbData array correlates to the columns in the table for the insert.
The table is called "content" and it has a constraint on the second column that it cannot be null. It is named 'CText'.

The code that operates on the data array is in a function that is called within a loop for all of the file data. I am providing the contents of the function below without the function interface. For simplification purposes I have included code that connects to the database, but the code that actually creates the database connection resides outside the function.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
...
$queryText = "insert into content values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$query = mysqli->prepare($queryText);
$query->bind_param('dsds',$dbData[0],$dbData[1],$dbData[2],$dbData[3]);
if (!$query->execute()) {
   echo '<br>Execute failed: (' . $query->errno . ') . $query->error;
   echo '<br>dbData[1]: ' .  $dbData[1];
}
```

The insert works for most of the $dbData record data, but I get this error on a few of the records:

> Execute failed: (1048) Column 'CText' cannot be null
>   CText: {data printed here that is truncated after what appears to be a line return in the string content}

My question is whether the bind may have issues with certain characters, like a line feed/carriage return or some other combination. I have not set a character encoding in the code so the default encoding is in use.

Comment: You can use `var_dump($dbData[1])` right where you see that error message and when you get it you will also see what value was there which caused the issue

Comment: var_dump showed a string(51)" {content} ".

Comment: The content is actually about 600 characters that is stored in the array that the bind uses.

Comment: Just looked at the hex characters after the truncation and found that they are '0D' and '0A'. (Guess the content is from a windows computer) I'm wondering if the bind is having problems with those characters?

Comment: Point is the the string itself is not being generated fine otherwise atleast var_dump would have shown all 600 characters in length

Comment: Good suggestion! I was only var_dumping after the bind, so I var_dumped prior to the bind and found that it was truncated also at the same point in the data - two hex characters ('0Dx' and 0Ax'). Thanks for the tip - will pick up the debug from the file interface now and go from there. Thanks!

Comment: So that's what was happening - the CR/LF (0D/0A) in the file contents were messing up the fgets PHP function to read the file content so that the contents were not all there in the dbData array, which apparently affected the bind. My thanks for getting me thinking with a different approach to this bug!

Answer (score 2):

> whether the bind may have issues with certain characters, like a line feed/carriage return or some other combination.

No. There are no issues with bind. The only reason for such error message is when data IS null.

Here goes simple checklist for solving all the problems of the kind.

1. Trust your eyes. You are not a sole user of mysqli prepared statements. There are millions of them, and noone experienced such a problem yet. Means if database is reporting that value cannot be null, then value IS null.
2. Anyway, if you still thinks that there is a bug - create an **isolated, reprobuceable code example**. Means not just create unworkable sketch to show to the readers, but a complete working example that anyone can reproduce. Such as

   ```
   $mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
   $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE content ...");
   $queryText = "insert into content values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
   $query = $mysqli->prepare($queryText);
   $dbData[0] = 0;
   $dbData[1] = 'some text that yo think is causing the error';
   $dbData[2] = 0;
   $dbData[3] = 'some another text';
   $query->bind_param('dsds',$dbData[0],$dbData[1],$dbData[2],$dbData[3]);
   if (!$query->execute()) {
      echo '<br>Execute failed: (' . $query->errno . ') . $query->error;
      echo '<br>dbData[1]: ' .  $dbData[1];
   }
   ```

   without loops. without any code that is not shown - but a complete, working example that produces the noted error.
3. After failing with such an example, start debugging your code, to find a logical error either with program flow or the way you debug it.

You have to realize that this kind of questions ("I have a bug in PHP out of the clear sky") cannot have another receive without a reproduceable example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will take this approach on subsequent bug questions.